# Wordpress Multisite - Can't access subfolder sites dashboard

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am new to WordPress Multi-site and I am seeing a weird issue.

I have installed a new instance of WordPress, enabled multi-site using sub-folders. The only issue is when I create a new website, it doesn't show correctly and I cannot access the new websites dashboard.

I have added these lines to **wp-config.php**

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '104.238.186.88');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Here is an example of a newly created site, it's as if it's only half installed? http://104.238.186.88/testing/

If you need any more info please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue on google cloud, I edit both files but nothing happens on my WordPress installation. It looks like the multisite is off. Do you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to make the following changes:

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

on some hosting configurations it needs to be:

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', 'false');
```

Also, I am kind of shooting in the dark here since you have not specified whether this is a root domain installation or if it is a subdomain installation, both of which potentially have their own unique problems, and how exactly your create new site "page" appears in your dashboard, but you might try making the following changes to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
```

and change to:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 [L]
```

Comment: THAAANK YOOOOU!!! IT helped me a lot after HOURS!!! - The new rewrite rules made my day! :)